# Serving root-level static files in a Vue app

Tags: webpack, vue.js

A Vue-CLI generated app stores the static files in `static` and due to the default config,

```
dev: {
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    // ...
}
```

they're accessible as:

```
<img src="/static/subfolder/filename.extension">
```

But there are some static files that I'd like to serve from root (e.g. `ads.txt`, `robots.txt`, `favicon.ico`, etc). So, at this point, I'm trying to serve all my statics from root (it's ok since I already have subfolders like `static/images/`)

Honestly, I don't get why `assetsPublicPath: '/'` actually requires `/static` to access those files, but following this logic I tried:

```
assetsPublicPath: '../'
```

It didn't work (obviously?). Any idea on how should I modify my config to achieve what I want?

*Note: I used Vue CLI 3 and the config's template is vuejs-templates/webpack 1.3.1*

Comment: At least the newer versions of vue-cli generates a webpack.config.js with `new CopyWebpackPlugin(
      [
        {
          from: 'public',
          to: 'dist',
          ignore: [
            'index.html',
            '.DS_Store'
          ]
        }
      ]
    ),` (thus copying anything in /public to /dist, so if you put your files there, and update I guess?) No idea about template but peeking with vue inspect (`@vue/cli v3.0.0-beta.16`)

Comment: Thank you @ippi. That did the job.